# Running Scala test with gradle scala plugin

Tags: gradle, gradle-scala

Using the latest version of gradle (2.10) with the [Scala Plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/scala_plugin.html) enabled, I'm trying to execute the tests located at `src/test/scala`.

But there seems to be no tasks to run these:

```
$ ./gradlew tasks
....
Verification tasks
------------------
check - Runs all checks.
test - Runs the unit tests.
```

None of these 2 tasks will execute my Scala tests. The only tests that get executed are those in `src/test/java`. My Scala tests tests are using `Specs2` using the following dependencies for test (`build.gradle`):

```
apply plugin: 'scala'

dependencies {
    testCompile(
        'org.specs2:specs2-core_2.12.0-M3:3.6.6-scalaz-7.2.0'
    )
}
```

I checked: the tests are getting compiled when using `./gradlew compileTestScala`.

What needs to be done to execute these tests?

Answer (score 3):

Ok, it was easy:

```
import org.specs2.runner.JUnitRunner
@RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner])
class FooSpec extends Specification {
  // test code
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution: using gradle plugin com.github.maiflai.scalatest

For such solution, Scala tests will be ran using org.scalatest.tools.Runner.

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.13.3'
    testImplementation 'org.scalatest:scalatest_2.13:3.2.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
    testImplementation 'com.vladsch.flexmark:flexmark-all:0.35.10'
}
```

version of flexmark is important because of scalatest framework hard coded such version in their code